# Getting BadCredentialsException in password change openldap spring

Tags: spring, ldap, passwords, credentials, openldap

I have openldap running on my localhost, i am trying to change user account password from my spring application but i am getting below Exception.

Please help.

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Authentication for password change failed.
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsManager$3.executeWithContext(LdapUserDetailsManager.java:204) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:817) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadWrite(LdapTemplate.java:812) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsManager.changePassword(LdapUserDetailsManager.java:191) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.atulsia.controller.UserController.getTemplate(UserController.java:417) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.atulsia.controller.UserController.getAllUsers(UserController.java:437) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
```

Code:

```
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl("ldap://localhost:389");
    contextSource.setUserDn("cn=Anil Pawar,cn=mts,ou=mm,dc=example,dc=com");
    contextSource.setPassword("123456");
    try {
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    LdapTemplate template = new LdapTemplate();
    template.setContextSource(contextSource);

    LdapUserDetailsManager ldapUserDetailsManager  = new LdapUserDetailsManager(template.getContextSource());
    ldapUserDetailsManager.changePassword("123456", "111111");
```